# Extract tweets with specific character from a list of account

Tags: r, rtweet, twitter-api-v2

I want to get the timeline (10 tweets, for example) of a list of profiles, but I want to get only the tweets which contain a specific character or string.

```
profiles<- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
keyword <- "apple"

tweets <- get_timeline(
  user = profiles,
  q = #I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE TO GET TWEETS THAT CONTAIN keyword: can't use grepl()
     #because the vector should be tweets... maybe with an if statement but I can't find the syntax
  n = 10,
  since_id = NULL,
  max_id = NULL,
  home = FALSE,
  parse = TRUE,
  check = TRUE,
  retryonratelimit = NULL,
  verbose = TRUE,
  token = NULL)
```

Comment: Is this a reproducible example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `q = "a OR b OR c OR d OR apple"`, I recommend reading the [official documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-query) of the API about which logical operators are available and how to use them. rtweet doesn't use the twitter API v2 yet (only for the streaming endpoints at the 1.1.0 release)